# How to test for pointer equality in Python ctypes?

Tags: python, ctypes, ffi

If I have the following C library

```c
#include <stdint.h>

int64_t* foo(int64_t *x) {
    return x;
}
```

and I invoke the function from Python ctypes like so:

```py
ptr = (ctypes.c_int64 * 100)()
rval = api.foo(ptr)
```

Naively I'd assume I can just `assertEqual(rval, ptr)`, but that fails. Printing `rval` and  `ptr` respectively I get

```
<reference_project.LP_c_longlong object at 0x0000021A563BBDC0>
<tests.c_longlong_Array_100 object at 0x0000021A563BBF40>
```

How can I compare `ptr` and `rval` for equality from Python?

Comment: I was expecting this to work if you fix the types, but nope. It looks like ctypes just doesn't have pointer comparison.

Comment: Actually, it looks like ctypes doesn't implement any comparison operations for any types at all.

Comment: (In "fix the types", I was including converting `ptr` to an actual pointer - currently, it's an array. `actual_ptr = ctypes.cast(ptr, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int64))` would perform that conversion.)

Comment: Fixed example; I made an oopsie when simplifying my code for SO.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, casting the pointers to `c_void_p` and taking `.value` seems to do the job:

```py
ptr_via_void = ctypes.cast(ptr, ctypes.c_void_p).value
rval_via_void = ctypes.cast(rval, ctypes.c_void_p).value

print(ptr_via_void)  # 2373661818336
print(rval_via_void) # 2373661818336

assertEqual(ptr_via_void, rval_via_void)
```

However, just omitting `.value` does *not* work:

```py
ptr_via_void = ctypes.cast(ptr, ctypes.c_void_p)
rval_via_void = ctypes.cast(rval, ctypes.c_void_p)

print(ptr_via_void)  # c_void_p(1988667444176)
print(rval_via_void) # c_void_p(1988667444176)

# Although both print the same value, this FAILS:
assertEqual(ptr_via_void, rval_via_void)
```

I can't believe there is seemingly no better way.

Comment: Even `c_int(1) == c_int(1)` returns `False`, but `c_int(1).value == c_int(1).value` returns `True`.